# Refreshing in browser changes template in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm having a weird problem with my angular app. When the user is logged in and hits "refresh" in the browser, the app loads the log-in template which is part of the main index.html file. It does not, however, kill the user session, but the user can't get any where else in the app without re-authenticating. Can anyone offer advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user refreshes the browser, your entire angular application disappears and gets restarted.  That's how SPAs ("Single Page Apps") work.

If you want to have the user not log in every time they do this, you have to save enough information in the browser itself to know that he or she has already logged in.  You can do this by storing some information either in a cookie or HTML5 local storage, and checking to see if the login information is stored before you call your authentication service.

Also, if you use standard http BASIC authentication the browser itself will cache the authentication credentials.